# ¿Como puedo imprimir desde raspberry pi 3 b+ (raspbian) usando python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

He estado batallando para lograr imprimir con raspberry, logré hacerlo 
 utilizando CUPS(Common Unix Printing System) con esto logré que raspberry reconociera la impresora (EPSON LX-300 )a través de USB , ahora quiero lograr imprimir desde raspberry pero usan python. Lo he intentado con este script

```
f=open("lpt1:","wb")
#comentario #he intentado("prn","lpr","usb001","dev/lp1" entre otros )
f.write("\nEsto es una prueba\n")
f.close
```

Pero no he obtenido resultado alguno.

Estos son los datos de mi impresora.